# A more effective way to apply std::set_difference for std::map

Tags: c++, algorithm

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference
I want to find the differences of 2 maps -- just by comparing the keys.

```c
map<string, int> m1 = { {"abc", 1},{"ttt", 2}, {"ccc", 3}, };
map<string, int> m2 = { {"abc", 3},{"bbb", 2}, {"ccc", 3}, };

std::vector<std::pair<string, int>> diff;
std::set_difference(m1.begin(), m1.end(), m2.begin(), m2.end(), std::inserter(diff, diff.begin()),
    [](auto& a, auto& b) { return a.first < b.first; });

for (auto& dif : diff)
{
    cout << dif.first << endl;
}
```

That works well and finds "ttt" out. But my real second type is a heavy type instead of an int.

`std::vector<std::pair<string, heavyType>> diff;`

Storing the heavyType is low performance. Is there a better way to achieve the result with high performance?

Comment: What does "low performance" mean?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik diff has to store both the key and value as a pair. But I only need the keys. And when the second type is not a int but something heavy like a vector, it wastes the time and memory.

Comment: That would also apply to the map itself as well. The same copying penalty also applies to the map too, so you should store smart pointers to the "heavy type" in the map, and you'll get a smart pointer in the vector too. Copying smart pointers around is negligible overhead.

Comment: Implement your own inserter and insert_iterator.

Comment: [`ranges::set_difference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/set_difference) (new in C++20) accepts projection functions in addition to the comparator; this should let you work on just the keys. Pre-C++20, either implement your own equivalent of `set_difference`, or your own output iterator that would do the projection.

Comment: So you want the result to just be `std::vector<string>` containing the keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to store the keys of the pairs produced by `set_difference`, you can use the range-v3 library:

```
namespace rv = ranges::views;

auto diff = rv::set_difference(m1, m2, [](auto& a, auto& b) { 
                                             return a.first < b.first; 
                                       }) 
          | rv::keys
          | ranges::to<std::vector<std::string>>;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5735oqYMT).